# start download to Apple hosted in-app content

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Ok so I'm not able to get hosted content to download from the Apple servers and I don't know exactly why. I am able to make purchases and complete the purchase for in-apps stored locally in the app. How do I download the content after the purchase has been made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at SKPaymentTransactionObserver. You must register as observer, then implement all the delegate methods and set yourself as delegate. Take a look at [SKPaymentQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) -startDownloads: method. After you call this, delegate will get called every time the download status updates. At the end you must copy the downloaded file from the temporary directory to your documents or library folder.